# How exactly works @RequestBody annotation and how it is related to the HttpMessageConverter interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, annotations

I am studying how Spring handle **REST** web services and I have some doubts related to the concept of the **HttpMessageConverter**.

On the official documentation I can read:

> Strategy interface that specifies a converter that can convert from
>   and to HTTP requests and responses.

So the **HttpMessageConverter** seems to be an interface but what exactly is a **strategy interface**? Is something related to the **strategy pattern** or not?

So from what I have understand Spring automatically provide some implementations registered by default when using **@EnableWebMvc** or

But what exactly does these implementation? Can you provide me a practical example?

I think that it works in this way:

For example a client perform an HttpRequest putting in the body of this request a **JSON** message (I am not so practical but I think that I can do something like this), then the controller that handle this HttpRequst use an implementation of **HttpMessageConverter** to convert this JSON message into a model object. I think that it is true also the vice versa.

Is my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Another doubt is related to the **@RequestBody** annotation (that I think it is related to the previous topic).

I have this example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/orders/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) // 204
public void updateOrder(@RequestBody Order updatedOrder, @PathVariable("id") long id) {
    // process updated order data and return empty response
    orderManager.updateOrder(id, updatedOrder);
}
```

So I think that **@RequestBody Order updatedOrder** take the value of the **updatedOrder** input parameter from the body of the HttpRequest and then convert it with into an **Order** object using an implementation of **HttpMessageConverter**.

Is it right or am I missing something? If it is right how can chose the right converter?

For example here I found another example similiar to the previous one: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public void addPet(@RequestBody Pet pet, Model model) {
    // implementation omitted
}
```

I think that here it is explicitly specified that it have to use a JSON to MODEL OBJECT converter. Why in the previous example is not specified? How can chose the right converter?

Tnx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Handler method parameters are generated by Spring's `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and handler method return values are processed by Spring's `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`. The implementation that deals with both `@ResponseBody` and `@RequestBody` is `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`.

One of these is registered by default (`@EnableWebMvc` configuration) with a default list of `HttpMessageConverter` instances. This is done in `WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addDefaultHttpMessageConverters(List)`. You can find the source code and see which ones are added and in what order.

When Spring goes to generate an argument for a `@RequestBody` parameter, it loops through the `HttpMessageConverter` instances, checks if that instance `HttpMessageConverter#canRead` the content type given in the request and can generate an instance of the parameter type. If it can, Spring will use that `HttpMessageConverter` to produce an argument. If it can't, Spring will skip it and try the next instance, until it runs out. At which point, it will throw an exception.

For `@ResponseBody`, the process is the same except Spring now uses `HttpMessageConverter#canWrite`. It will check if the `HttpMessageConverter` can serialize the return type and generate response content that fits the content type that is expected in the response (given in the `Accept` request header).

The `consumes` attribute of `@RequestParam`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
```

has nothing to do with the strategy declared above. The only thing that `consumes` does here is to restrict the mapping of the handler. For example, take these two handlers

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets", method = RequestMethod.POST)

@RequestMapping(value = "/pets", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
```

The first one can handle any request to `/pets` with any content type. The second can only handle those requests to `/pets` with the content type `application/json`.

Comment: So how does it maps a particular http input field to the particular variable of that object ? Say name, email from html to name and email characteristics of the class.

Comment: @ShivamPapat That entirely depends on the content type and the `HttpMessageConverter` implementation that's used to parse it. For JSON, it might use an implementation that relies on the Jackson library (and however that works).